# Can we have a compiler running in embedded device

Tags: embedded-linux

It may sound weird but I would like to know if we can have compiler in embedded device (lets say gcc support on imx6).

Comment: Answer for your question is `yes`.

Comment: @rkosegi can you provide the details for the same? it'd be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is not uncommon to have target tools, but is is not trivial.  A non-native (from the host perspective) compiler must be cross-compiled for the target architecture.  You didn't provide any details, but maybe your build system can build target tools for you.  Of course, you need much more than just a compiler.  You probably need make, autotools, and probably more.  It depends on what you are trying to compile on the target.

Your best bet would be to gain some proficiency using a cross-compiler environment.  If you haven't already, you might check out the Yocto Project.  It supports i.mx6 (and much more) and probably provides a path to get target tools on your board.

Good luck!

Comment: *"it is not uncommon to have target tools"* -- Maybe that's true for hobbyists and their SBCs (e.g. RPi), but that's a bogus claim for the real world.

Comment: @challinan I've my cross compiler on an ubuntu 16.04 LTS (on X86_64 arch) machine, where I build my applications for the target i.mx6 then I'll copy them to the target and start executing (of course, all this is once the OS is up). So, my question is can we have a complete set of tools and cross compiler on target board itself so that I can compile and execute from my target. Note: Initially I'll copy the code files to target that needs to be build as I'm unsure about the text editor support for i.mx6

Comment: The answer is yes, you can but you shouldn't. It doesn't make much sense to compile on the target while you are already able to compile on the host for your target.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni, I'm interested in having a compiler on target (i.MX6 in my case) as I don't have any memory limitations in i.MX6 and also if I can have the support on target, I can avoid the cycle of building the application on the host, then copying to an MMC and copy to target and then run. Can you point me any resource/some detailed explanation about how we can have the compiler support on target would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To arm arch, it will be easy to get target compiler, linaro ubuntu of linaro project will provide a completely solution for arm arch, it can provide GNOME desktop、toolchain and informative tools on your target.

You can get more info from the following link:

https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should easy enough.. What version of cross-compiler do you have in your machine, download the matching gcc compiler from here https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/

Now what you want to do is cross-compile the GCC which you downloaded using the crosscompiler which you already have.

Following is an example of compiling 4.7.4, NOTE: replace the HOST and BUILD according to your platform:

```
   ./contrib/download_prerequisites

   cd ..

   mkdir objdir
   cd objdir

   ../gcc-4.7.4/configure --build=$BUILD \
               --host=$HOST \
               --target=$HOST \
               --prefix=/usr \
               --disable-nls \
               --enable-languages=c,c++ \
               --with-float=hard 

   make -j $JOBS

   make DESTDIR=<path_where_to_install> install
```